# Using environment variable in html file

Tags: javascript, html

```
Here my HTML code...
1.<?xml version="1.0"?>
2.<html>
3.<head>
4.    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fbmodel.css">
5.    <script src="src/jquery-latest.js"></script>
6.    <script src="src/jquery.fbmodel.js"></script>
7.    <script type="text/javascript">
8.    <!--$(document).ready(function() {
9.             var line;
10.             var read_testsuites = 0;
11.             var read_libraries = 0;
12.             var read_klockwork_projects = 0;
13.             for (line in lines) {
14.                     if (match_found = lines[line].match(/Project:\s*(\w+)/i)) {
15.                           project_name = match_found[1];
16.                            if (project_name.match(/^HSS/i)) {
17.                             project_name = "HSS";
18.                          }
19.
20.                var repo = "/vobs/ims_hss1/moduletest/testcases/" + project_name;
21.                populateOption(repo, repo, repository);
22.            }
23.      }
24.     <tr>
25.     <th align="left" bgcolor="lightgrey" class="masterTooltip" title="Specifies the obsolute folder                   path of the Module Testing Framework specific debug log. Blank indicates logging is disabled.">MT Debug Folder Path</th>

26.     <td>
27.     <input type="text" id="mtLog" name="mtLog" size="70" value="/vobs/ims_hss1/moduletest/logs"/>
28.     <input type="checkbox" id="enableMtLog" name="enableMtLog" checked="true"/>
29.     </td>
30.     </tr>
31.     <tr>
```

In Line 20, repo is a path. I have an environment variable GITWORK which is /imsgit/work/v149kumar(v149kumar is my id. it will change if another user login).
I want to use this value of GITWORK before /vobs, it should like /imsgit/work/v149kumar/vobs/ims_hss1/testcases.

Now go to line number 27...
There also a path is given with /vobs/ims_hss1/, There also i want to have value of GITWORK before /vobs.

How to read the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE here.

As I am new to HTML, Please help me with this problem.

Comment: How do you know who is logged in? Are you talking like windows authentication / active directory? You can't get access to that here. If it's your own sites custom login, then you'll need the server to pass that along or set it in cookies.

Comment: Are you using any server-side language in conjuction with HTML? If yes, it should be easy to do. If not, you might want to look at Server-Side includes (SSI), not sure if that would help

Comment: I am working on git and taken local copy from server where many user can logs in. for them GITWORK value will be different, it will have userid of the user.

Comment: well that not major issue but see from line 24 to 31. there i have to read environment variable with <input tag> where value is present. have a look over there and please give me a useful way to achieve this. @Prescott

Answer (score 0):

you can use java script to read from HTML tags. Also you can use jquery for execution and render again into HTML tags/file.

Comment: In java script i got many different method like navigator, Wscript.shell.. many other. I dont know about JS. I works on C, C++. If u have any way then please explain me.

Comment: well that not major issue but see from line 24 to 31. there i have to read environment variable with <input tag> where value is present. have a look over there and please give me a useful way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a environment variable on the client side the answer is "You are not able to read it". You can ask user to enter the path you need and then store it in cookie or database.

It you're talking about server-side environment variable then it depends on what you are using on the server-size.

Comment: see other comment and please help me... @troolee